# Cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04 stopped working after menu editing

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

I have recently installed cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04 with success.
After installing MS Office with wine my menu got messy so I tried to edit it with alacarte.

After having found out that alacarte is not the proper way to edit it, I right clicked on the menu icon to edit. After just a few editing steps it breaks and cinnamon stopped working (no menus, no desktop icons, no applets, no window decoration, nothing).
Now, when I login with cinnamon I just get the background image.

I can login with gnome though.

I have tried to completely remove cinnamon and nemo and reinstall it but it didn't help.

I have no idea of how to get any king of diagnostics so if you ask something please explain how to do it or post a link with explanations.

Many thanks for the help, I hope I will not need to format the pc again to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon`

If that doesn't work, try creating a new user using `gksudo gnome-control-center user-accounts`, log in to that user, copy your data files from the old user then delete the old user using the user accounts menu.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal `sudo rm -rf ~/.cinnamon` this will remove your Cinnamon configuration. Log out then back in.

This will create another instance of the installed desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is reinstalling of cinnamon

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```